# Have to load video into div from JSON object, can this be done with knockout?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

In this task they want me to load the video that is in this JSON object into the corresponding player after the thumbnail is clicked. I don't have a real clue of how to do this if it's possible and I've researched it for the past hour and I cannot for the life of me find anything. My code is below

```
var json = {
    "available": true,
    "screens": [{
            "id": "s01",
            "type": "Selector",
            "config": {
                "views": [{
                    "id": "sintel",
                    "type": "selectorItem",
                    "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/sintel/assets/img/thumb_sintel.png",
                    "title": "Sintel",
                    "description": "Small video. HTML5, native controls, start poster. Bottom, right social. Video + grid",
                    "info": "00:51"
                }, {
                    "id": "bbb",
                    "type": "selectorItem",
                    "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/bbb/assets/img/thumb_bbb.png",
                    "title": "Big Buck Bunny",
                    "description": "Large video. HTML5, custom controls, social hover. Video + replay",
                    "info": "00:33"
                }, {
                    "id": "walle",
                    "type": "selectorItem",
                    "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/img/thumb_walle.png",
                    "title": "WALL-E",
                    "description": "Small video. Youtube, custom controls. Left social. Video + carousel.",
                    "info": "02:30"
               }]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "sintel",
            "type": "BrandWrapper",
            "config": {
                "views": [{
                    "id": "sintelBranding",
                    "type": "fullBranding",
                    "url": "sintel_single.png"
                }, {
                    "id": "sintelPlayer",
                    "type": "smPlayerIframe",
                    "files": [{
                            "type": "mp4",
                            "codecs": "h264,aac",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/sintel/assets/video/sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mp4",
                            "codecs": "avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/sintel/assets/video/sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ogv",
                            "codecs": "theora,vorbis",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/sintel/assets/video/sintel_trailer-1080p.ogv"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "flv",
                            "codecs": "h264,aac",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/sintel/assets/video/sintel_trailer-1080p.flv"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": "sintelLeftClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "leftTower",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "https://durian.blender.org/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "sintelHeaderClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "header",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "https://durian.blender.org/about/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "sintelFooterClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "footer",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "https://durian.blender.org/gallery/"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "bbb",
            "type": "BrandWrapper",
            "config": {
                "views": [{
                    "id": "bbbBrandingHeader",
                    "type": "header",
                    "url": "bbb_header.png"
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbBrandingLeft",
                    "type": "leftTower",
                    "url": "bbb_tower_left.png"
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbBrandingRight",
                    "type": "rightTower",
                    "url": "bbb_tower_right.png"
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbBrandingFooter",
                    "type": "footer",
                    "url": "bbb_footer.png"
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbPlayer",
                    "type": "smPlayerIframe",
                    "files": [{
                            "type": "mp4",
                            "codecs": "h264,aac",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/bbb/assets/video/bbb_trailer_1080p.mp4"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mp4",
                            "codecs": "avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/bbb/assets/video/bbb_trailer_1080p.mp4"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ogv",
                            "codecs": "theora,vorbis",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/bbb/assets/video/bbb_trailer_1080p.ogv"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "flv",
                            "codecs": "h264,aac",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/bbb/assets/video/bbb_trailer_1080p.flv"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbLeftClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "leftTower",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "https://peach.blender.org/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbHeaderClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "header",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "https://peach.blender.org/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbRightClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "rightTower",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "https://peach.blender.org/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "bbbFooterClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "footer",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "https://peach.blender.org/"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "walle",
            "type": "BrandWrapper",
            "config": {
                "assetPath": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/img/",
                "sizeTemplate": "smallVideo",
                "views": [{
                    "id": "walleBranding",
                    "type": "fullBranding",
                    "url": "walle_single.png"
                }, {
                    "id": "wallePlayer",
                    "type": "smPlayerIframe",
                    "files": [{
                            "type": "mp4",
                            "codecs": "h264,aac",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/video/wall-e-trailer-3_9_1280x544.mp4"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mp4",
                            "codecs": "avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/video/wall-e-trailer-3_9_1280x544.mp4"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ogv",
                            "codecs": "theora,vorbis",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/video/wall-e-trailer-3_9_1280x544.ogv"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "flv",
                            "codecs": "h264,aac",
                            "url": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/video/wall-e-trailer-3_9_1280x544.flv"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": "wallLeftClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "leftTower",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "http://movies.disney.com/wall-e/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "walleHeaderClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "header",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "http://movies.disney.com/wall-e/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "walleRightClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "rightTower",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "http://movies.disney.com/wall-e/"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "walleFooterClickArea",
                    "type": "brandClickArea",
                    "area": "footer",
                    "clickParams": {
                        "value": "http://movies.disney.com/wall-e/"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: screens">
  <div class="container" data-bind="with: config">
    <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: views">    
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
    <!--This line should load the video-->
          <img class="card-img-top" data-bind="attr: { src: thumbnail }"> 
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title" data-bind="text:title"> </h5> 
            <p class="card-text" data-bind="text:info"> </p>                      
          </div><!-- card content -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anything at all would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on demo [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp), you could using the `<video>` tag:

```
<!-- ko if: type() === 'smPlayerIframe' -->
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <!-- ko foreach: files -->
  <source data-bind="attr: { src: url, type: 'video/' + type() }" />
  <!-- /ko -->
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<!-- /ko -->
```